# Dualizable objects in homotopy category of chain complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, derived-categories, stable-homotopy

The proposition 1.9 from "Duality, Trace and Transfer" by Dold and Puppe states that:

Given a commutative ring $R$, a chain complex of $R$-modules is strongly dualizable in $Ho(Ch(R))$, the homotopy category of chain complexes, iff it has the same homotopy type of a strongly dualizable object in $Ch(R)$.

However, they omit the proof (an I can't find the references cited there). I was wondering how can one prove such a thing.